# In Windows, how do programs bypass OS cache?

Tags: windows, cache

Some programs have an option to avoid using OS cache when access files(for example, Virtualbox and qbittorrent). They don't need admin privilege so they definitely not disable the file system cache.

How could a program read/write directly with the disk and bypass the OS cache, only for itself?

Comment: What do you mean by OS cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an option of the Windows file-opening API function
[CreateFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx).

The option is called `FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH` defined as :

> Write operations will not go through any intermediate cache, they will go directly to disk.

For more information see :

- [File Buffering (Windows)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc644950(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [INFO: FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH and FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/99794/info-file-flag-write-through-and-file-flag-no-buffering)

The latest link says in addition :

> The FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH flag for CreateFile() causes any writes made to that handle to be written directly to the file without being buffered.
>   [...]
>   The FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING takes this concept one step further and eliminates all read-ahead file buffering and disk caching as well, so that all reads are guaranteed to come from the file and not from any system buffer or disk cache. When using FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING, disk reads and writes must be done on sector boundaries, and buffer addresses must be aligned on disk sector boundaries in memory.

It wouldn't surprise me to find that not many products use the FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING flag.

Comment: Is there a way to disable this behavior, so that apps cannot bypass cache no matter what?

Answer (score 1):

Open the file with `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING`

See the `CreateFile` function on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx)